# Magento 2.2.2 - Add Custom Wrapper using XML

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, containers

I need to add additional wrapper inside `page.wrapper` so that other containers will be inside by custom wrapper.

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">

        <container name="my-custom-wrapper" htmlClass="my-custom-wrapper" htmlTag="div">

        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />

        </container>

    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

**Expected HTML**

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="my-custom-wrapper">
     ... all other containers ....
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

in your layout file, you can add using code below :

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="container-name" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container-class">
   </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: The above snippet is generic. Could you post wrt to my code?

Comment: What if it is not working? This xml is loaded into the page tree, but there is no div.container-class created